# Magento 2 - How to check if Redis is working

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

In magento 2 I recently configure Redis in `app/etc/env.php` file.

But I don't know how to check if the configuration is ok and if Redis is working well with magento.

Is there a way to make sure of that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Once you have configured redis in `app/etc/env.php` you can use below commands to check your redis configuration is working fine or not.

**Redis monitor command:**

```
redis-cli monitor
```

Run `redis-cli monitor` command in your terminal and refresh your storefront page and you’ll see output similar to the following for session storage

```
1476824834.187250 [0 127.0.0.1:52353] "select" "0"
1476824834.187587 [0 127.0.0.1:52353] "hmget" "sess_sgmeh2k3t7obl2tsot3h2ss0p1" "data" "writes"
1476824834.187939 [0 127.0.0.1:52353] "expire" "sess_sgmeh2k3t7obl2tsot3h2ss0p1" "1200"
1476824834.257226 [0 127.0.0.1:52353] "select" "0"
1476824834.257239 [0 127.0.0.1:52353] "hmset" "sess_sgmeh2k3t7obl2tsot3h2ss0p1" "data" "_session_validator_data|a:4:{s:11:\"remote_addr\";s:12:\"10.235.34.14\";s:8:\"http_via\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"http_x_forwarded_for\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"http_user_agent\";s:115:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36\";}_session_hosts|a:1:{s:12:\"10.235.32.10\";b:1;}admin|a:0:{}default|a:2:{s:9:\"_form_key\";s:16:\"e331ugBN7vRjGMgk\";s:12:\"visitor_data\";a:3:{s:13:\"last_visit_at\";s:19:\"2016-10-18 21:06:37\";s:10:\"session_id\";s:26:\"sgmeh2k3t7obl2tsot3h2ss0p1\";s:10:\"visitor_id\";s:1:\"9\";}}adminhtml|a:0:{}customer_base|a:1:{s:20:\"customer_segment_ids\";a:1:{i:1;a:0:{}}}checkout|a:0:{}" "lock" "0"
... more ...
```

And you will see output like given below for page caching:

```
1476826133.810090 [0 127.0.0.1:52366] "select" "1"
1476826133.816293 [0 127.0.0.1:52367] "select" "0"
1476826133.817461 [0 127.0.0.1:52367] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_GLOBAL__DICONFIG" "d"
1476826133.829666 [0 127.0.0.1:52367] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_DICONFIG049005964B465901F774DB9751971818" "d"
1476826133.837854 [0 127.0.0.1:52367] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_INTERCEPTION" "d"
1476826133.868374 [0 127.0.0.1:52368] "select" "1"
1476826133.869011 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "select" "0"
1476826133.869601 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_DEFAULT_CONFIG_CACHE_DEFAULT__10__235__32__1080MAGENTO2" "d"
1476826133.872317 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_INITIAL_CONFIG" "d"
1476826133.879267 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_GLOBAL_PRIMARY_PLUGIN_LIST" "d"
1476826133.883312 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_GLOBAL__EVENT_CONFIG_CACHE" "d"
1476826133.898431 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_STAGING_UPDATE_1" "d"
1476826133.898794 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_RESOLVED_STORES_D1BEFA03C79CA0B84ECC488DEA96BC68" "d"
1476826133.905738 [0 127.0.0.1:52369] "hget" "zc:k:ea6_DEFAULT_CONFIG_CACHE_STORE_DEFAULT_10__235__32__1080MAGENTO2" "d"

... more ...

1476826210.634998 [0 127.0.0.1:52439] "hmset" "zc:k:ea6_MVIEW_CONFIG" "d" "a:18:{s:19:\"design_config_dummy\";a:4:{s:7:\"view_id\";s:19:\"design_config_dummy\";s:12:\"action_class\";s:39:\"Magento\\Theme\\Model\\Indexer\\Mview\\Dummy\";s:5:\"group\";s:7:\"indexer\";s:13:\"subscriptions\";a:0:{}}s:14:\"customer_dummy\";a:4:{s:7:\"view_id\";s:14:\"customer_dummy\";s:12:\"action_class\";s:42:\"Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Indexer\\Mview\\Dummy\";s:5:\"group\";s:7:\"indexer\";s:13:\"subscriptions\";a:0:{}}s:13:\"cms_page_grid\";a:4:{s:7:\"view_id\";s:13:\"cms_page_grid\";s:12:\"action_class\";s:43:\"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Indexer\\Category\\Flat\";s:5:\"group\";s:7:\"indexer\";s:13:\"subscriptions\";a:1:{s:8:\"cms_page\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:8:\"cms_page\";s:6:\"column\";s:7:\"page_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";N;}}}s:21:\"catalog_category_flat\";a:4:{s:7:\"view_id\";s:21:\"catalog_category_flat\";s:12:\"action_class\";s:43:\"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Indexer\\Category\\Flat\";s:5:\"group\";s:7:\"indexer\";s:13:\"subscriptions\";a:6:{s:23:\"catalog_category_entity\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:23:\"catalog_category_entity\";s:6:\"column\";s:9:\"entity_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";N;}s:31:\"catalog_category_entity_decimal\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:31:\"catalog_category_entity_decimal\";s:6:\"column\";s:9:\"entity_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";s:71:\"Magento\\CatalogStaging\\Model\\Mview\\View\\Category\\Attribute\\Subscription\";}s:27:\"catalog_category_entity_int\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:27:\"catalog_category_entity_int\";s:6:\"column\";s:9:\"entity_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";s:71:\"Magento\\CatalogStaging\\Model\\Mview\\View\\Category\\Attribute\\Subscription\";}s:28:\"catalog_category_entity_text\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:28:\"catalog_category_entity_text\";s:6:\"column\";s:9:\"entity_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";s:71:\"Magento\\CatalogStaging\\Model\\Mview\\View\\Category\\Attribute\\Subscription\";}s:31:\"catalog_category_entity_varchar\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:31:\"catalog_category_entity_varchar\";s:6:\"column\";s:9:\"entity_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";s:71:\"Magento\\CatalogStaging\\Model\\Mview\\View\\Category\\Attribute\\Subscription\";}s:32:\"catalog_category_entity_datetime\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:32:\"catalog_category_entity_datetime\";s:6:\"column\";s:9:\"entity_id\";s:18:\"subscription_model\";s:71:\"Magento\\CatalogStaging\\Model\\Mview\\View\\Category\\Attribute\\Subscription\";}}}s:24:\"catalog_category_product\";a:4:{s:7:\"view_id\";s:24:\"catalog_category_product\";s:12:\"action_class\";s:46:\"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Indexer\\Category\\Product\";s:5:\"group\";s:7:\"indexer\";s:13:\"subscriptions\";a:2:{s:23:\"catalog_category_entity\";a:3:{s:4:\"name\";s:23:\"catalog_category_entity\";s:6:\"column\"

... more ...
```

**Redis ping command**

```
redis-cli ping
```

PONG should be the response of redis pong command.

If both commands succeeded, Redis is set up properly.

You can find more details about it [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html).

Comment: Thanks but I don't have access to Redis server. 
I just make the configuration in magento 2. 
Do you know if there is a way to check it only in magento ?

Comment: Redis is installed on the server side and you need to have access to the server to verify whether it is working fine or not. I cannot think of any way which you can use to to verify it's working fine or not without have server access.

Answer (score 0):

If redis is enabled you can confirm it is functional by clearing the session folder of files. Providing files do not regenerate when you are log in or add to cart then you are using redis for session storage.

If nothing is generated in session folder your configuration is good.  If you want to test performance you want a siege test (or similar) but choose a high number of concurrent visits.

For a complete picture you really need access to that server